# How to import MathTool in Velocity in file template in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I am working on adding a file template of a Java class in IntelliJ using Apache Velocity. I want to use pow() function in the template but I don't know how to import it. According to the official guide https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/MathTool.html#pow() I need to add

```
 <tool>
   <key>math</key>
   <scope>application</scope>
   <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool</class>
 </tool>
```

But I don't know where to put this xml file. File template is just a single class template file created in `.idea` directory which has no application structure. Does anyone know how to import this?

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using? In which context or framework? A standalone application of your own? A webapp? Do you have access to the Java side of the initialization? Or are you using Spring?

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson It's in the file template section of IntelliJ. I've got response from JetBrain support saying they don't support this kind of import. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how IntelliJ IDEA is relevant here, further than for code colorization. You don't need your *editor* to understand everything you do in your application. My question is rather *how* you will run your application, that is *which object* will prepare the context for templates rendering.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support this kind of imports. [Feature request is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: Thanks. I've got the same answer from JetBrain support.